# trying to make wemos d1 code modular causes collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status exit status 1

Tags: programming, c, compilation-errors, cpp

```
#include "connection.h"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Funcs::Connect conn;
  conn.connectWifi();
}

void loop() {

}
```

then **connection.h** file:

```
// connection.h

namespace Funcs
{
  class Connect 
  {
    public:
      void connectWifi();
  };
}
```

and then **connection.cpp**

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include "connection.h"
const char* ssid     = "ssid";
const char* password = "password";


namespace Funcs
{

  void connectWifi() {
    // Connect to WiFi network
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(10);
      Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("WiFi connected with ip ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  }
}
```

On compiling I get this error:

```
/Library/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/cores/esp8266/HardwareSerial.h:76: 
undefined reference to `Funcs::Connect::connectWifi()'
```

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board WeMos D1 R1.
```

But I do not have `Funcs::Connect::connectWifi()` in my code, it was in old code.

Comment: Your connection.cpp is incorrect. Take a look [Class code and header files](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/89-class-code-and-header-files/) to see how class methods should be defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling Funcs::Connect::connectWifi() right here:

```
conn.connectWifi();
```

since conn is of type Funcs::Connect

But you defined a function Funcs::connectWifi():

```
namespace Funcs
{

  void connectWifi() {
```

where I think you meant to have connectWifi be a member of that Connect class.

```
namespace Funcs
{

  void Connect::connectWifi() {
```

That's not the only issue with your code, you also create the instance in setup and let it go out of scope after calling just the one function.  But that's a different kind of error.  It's legal code, just probably doesn't do what you want.